# Android Studio - Video application crashes - Videoview & Mediaplayer - Can not play recording

Tags: java, android, video, android-intent

I have an application where I use a button to start the camera through intent to record video. This work fine and the application returns to mainactivity. When returned to mainactivity I would like last recorded video to be played in the VideoView. At this point my problem occur.

Im trying to follow the instructions on the link provided below, but something is obviously not correct.

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html

Logcat says I need to use Mediaplayer. Could someone help me out with some code?

Thanks in advance!

```
package com.example.t.videorecorder;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE=1;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void startCamera(View view){
    Intent intent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intentintent) {

    VideoView vW=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    if (requestCode==REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        Uri video= intent.getData();
        vW.setVideoURI(video);
    }
}
}
```

LogCat:

```
11-09 12:43:12.894 27047-27047/com.example.t.videorecorder E/MediaPlayer[Native]: Unable to create media player
11-09 12:43:12.896 27047-27047/com.example.t.videorecorder W/VideoView: Unable to open content: content://media/external/video/media/33789
java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
at android.media.MediaPlayer.nativeSetDataSource(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1061)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1050)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1004)
at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:353)
at android.widget.VideoView.access$2200(VideoView.java:72)
at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:664)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:579)
at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:238)
at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:8704)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1269)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1269)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1269)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1269)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1269)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1269)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1338)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5845)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to include the media Player:

```
vW.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
vW.requestFocus();
vW.start();
```

And add the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

In android marshmallow go to settings then app then go to the app and in the permission allow the Storage Access permission.

Comment: Pleasure is mine